# Android Studio ConstraintLayout GuideLines on Button while keeping it square

Tags: android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to keep all my views constraint to guidelines so that it'll always be relative and not mess up on different screens.

I ran into a problem where I have a button(using a background of an image with no text to control button size). That I'd like to keep square WHILE ALSO keep within guidelines... but of course, it cannot be that way since unless the resolution is square(which it never is) you cannot always have it square within guidelines.

Is there a way to enforce its size to be square while also keeping it somewhat relative and resizing based on screen size?

Comment: The easiest way is to make the width and height of the button fixed.  But I think you're probably looking for a more elegant/flexible solution.  But for many reading this, setting `layout_width=100dp` and `layout_height=100dp` could do the trick.

Comment: That's what I initially did... The problem with that is when very big or very small screens are included..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting, I think I got it.  The key is the `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` command.

In this layout, I have a button (using the pause icon as the background--it's easy to see if it's square or not) without text.  It is constrained to two gridlines that are 30% away from the top left corner.  You can of course modify as needed.

The width of the button is set to `wrap_content`, while the height is set to `0dp`, which denotes use the constraints.

But the big key is setting the `layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"`.  This forces the ratio to always be square.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vert_guide"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horiz_guide"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vert_guide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="30pt" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horiz_guide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="30pt" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Let me know how this works.  I haven't thoroughly tested this, so it may not work in every situation.

Comment: This is actually the closest it has gotten me! Sadly, due to us using wrap_content the image is gigantic lol. I tried using max_width but it seems to be completely ignored.

Is there a way to also limit the size based on screen size? The idea is that on whatever screen we put it on the button will take approximately the same amount of space.

Comment: I got it! Using what you showed me, I just had to constraint it to 3 guidelines. The idea is(I think) is that now, when the height is constrained(the third one is horizontal), The hight becomes relative and is forcing the width to be the same.
THank you!

Comment: Good catch!  That's actually a common way to section parts of the ConstraintLayout as well.